# Input regex greater than 0 react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I would like to allow numbers higher than 0  in an input field of a react app - javascript.  I don't want to have `0` only if it's the first letter. For example `1, 5, 15, 20, 500, 1000005` would be allowed, but `0.5` not.  I found this Regex online, however it blocks ALL 0's from being entered.

```
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={val}
        onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value.replace(/[^1-9]/g, ""))}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: use can use condition for this , which would be best case in my opinion

Comment: Simply add a `^ ` in front: `/^[^1-9]/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState }  from 'react';

export function App(props) {
 const [val, setVal] = useState("");
 return (
   <div className="App">
   <input
    value={val}
    onChange={(e) => {
      e.target.value>=1 ? setVal(e.target.value): setVal("")
    }}
    />
  </div>
 );
}
```

it will  only set value greater then 0

Comment: This allows 0.5, which it should not as per OP

Comment: Just replace the condition with greater than or equal to 1

Answer (score 0):

To enforce integers greater than 0 you can remove all non-digits, followed by removing leading zeros:

```
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={val}
        onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/^0+/, ''))}
      />
    </div>
  );
```